# Python KeyError: 0 when working with dictionary and functions

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so my question may seem easy to some but then again I'm stuck on my own so I need your help! This is the code that i am having trouble with:

```
def identify_language(sequence, **common_words):
    result = {}
    for i in common_words:            
        result[i] = 0
    for i in func_op(sequence.lower()):
        for j in common_words:
            if i in common_words[j]:
                result[j] += 1
    return sort(result[0][0])

...

dictionary = {'cro':list_cro, 'eng':list_cro}
language = identify_language('I had a little lamb. It was called Billy.', **dictionary)
```

I am trying to identify language based on samples which are in `list_cro` and `list_eng` (and hopefully others). I am getting `KeyError: 0`. Additionally, `sort` and `func_op` are working fine i tested then separately. What may be the problem?

Also, if i change order of arguments in function (putting list as a first argument and string as second) i am getting syntax error.
Thanks for listening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the function, `result` should look like this: `{'cro': X, 'eng': Y}`, where X and Y are numbers. I don't know what your dictionaries are, so I can't guess what the numbers are. Evaluating `result['eng']` will produce a number, as will `result['cro']`, but there is no `0` key in this dictionary.

Further, the second indexing operation will also give you issues. `result['eng'][0]` will give you an error because `result['eng']` is a number, and you can't index into a number.

What do you expect the output of this function to look like? Where is `sort` defined and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Sort is searching for a key with a highest assigned value! I made it work, but you gave me some helpful advice for future! Tnx!